# Backbone/PHP destroy/DELETE request error

Tags: php, ajax, json, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone.js with PHP on the server side. My PHP version is 5.3.6 and so supports namespaces.

I can make model `.save()` and `.fetch()` requests just fine, the requests are sent and the PHP handles the requests and returns json.

The problem I have is trying to do a `.destroy()` request (with which I *do* send an ID). The response from a `.destroy()` request returns an error and a `responseText` of:

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in <b>C:\myfolder\api.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Line 9 in api.php is just: `namespace App;` (which is the very first line in my PHP).

Like I said, `.save()` (POST) and `.fetch()` (GET) requests work, no errors on that line, but a `.destroy()` (DELETE) request does error on that line.

I'm using `ajaxPrefilter` to log the ajax options to the console, which shows:

```
dataType: "json"
type: "DELETE"
url: "/api/v1/authenticate/10"
```

All of which seems correct.

Why might I get such a PHP error for a RESTful `DELETE` request, and not for RESTful `POST` and `GET` requests..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, it turns out that I *was* using an older version of PHP, version 5.2.1.4 to be specific.

In IIS, my site was set to use 5.3.6 under "PHP Manager", however there was a "Handler Mapping" pointing `.php` files to 5.2.1.4.

So the error message was correct, my version of PHP didn't support namespaces.

**UPDATE**

After more checking, I understand better now. I had two handler mapping entries for `.php`. One for 5.3.6 (allowing `GET` & `POST`) and one for 5.2.1.4 (allowing all verbs including `DELETE`).

So my `GET` and `POST` verbs were handled by 5.3.6, but my `DELETE` was being handled by 5.2.1.4 - hence the namespace related error, but only on `DELETE` requests.

So, the lesson is... When using IIS and PHP, check your handler mappings for `.php` files to make sure you're using the correct version, and also check which verbs are accepted on your handler mappings.